# Schema for Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to provide structure to the firebase data tables. Hence, I want  to create a schema (similar to mongoose) based on which the entries to the database can be written. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two libraries then enable creating schema for firebase:

1. [Firebase Schema](https://github.com/ryanflorence/firebase-schema)
2. [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt)

Bolt is a library developed by firebase itself

Answer (score 0):

To validate the structure of data that can be written to the Firebase Realtime Database, you use the `.validate` clause in its server-side security rules. Instead of repeating them here, I'll refer you to its documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/